# passing php function to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, variables

Consider the following Jquery external script snippet for creating youtube iframes in modal windows:

```
$(function() {

    $(document).ready(function() {  

    var myPhpVa = '<?php echo embeddable($ytid);?>';

    $('a[name="modal"]').click(function(e) {

        $('<iframe width="560" height="315" src=myPhpVa frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>').appendTo('#dcontent');

    }

});
```

For some reason I get object not found. The PHP function is declared above this javascript, the declaration is:

```
function embeddable($ytid){
        return $embeddable = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$ytid;
    }
```

Any help for passing this PHP variable is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to both use $(document).ready(function(){}) and $(function(){}). They are both same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - assigning returned value is useless. Remove it:

```
function embeddable($ytid){
    return 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$ytid;
}
```

The same thing about `$(document).ready(function() {` and `$(function() {` - they are equal and doubled - remove one of them.

After you assign `myPhpVa` variable - write

```
alert(myPhpVa);
```

and check what it shows you.

Comment: the alert gives <?php echo embeddable() ?>

Comment: Ok - what is the extension of your file ? Is it `.html` or `.php` ? Are you running this page from PHP server or directly from your computer without any Apache server ?

Comment: i call this PHP from JS file and I have apache server running

Comment: Ok, so we have a solution. You cannot do that, because `.js` files are not parsed with `PHP`. If you want to do things like this, you have place this part of `JS` script into `.php` file and let server to execute `PHP` content. Then it will work.

Comment: Ok, could you give some sample code this js file is called modal.js php should echo the whole script?

Comment: Hmm.. I got an idea - just change file's extension from `.js` to `.php` - it will be parsed as a PHP, but you can it still include as a JS file (using `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.php"></script>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4526/discussion-between-hsz-and-george)

Answer (score 2):

I think the syntax of your code where you append the iframe to your html is incorrect.

```
    $('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + myPhpVa + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>').appendTo('#dcontent');
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not breaking out of the string to concat the `myPhpVa` into the js literal.  Try this:

```
$('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' +  myPhpVa + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>').appendTo('#dcontent');
```

If that doesn't work, alert the value of `myPhpVa` to see if its what you expect.